# Order an Azure app service certificate with terraform

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, terraform, azure-keyvault

I would like to order an App Service Certificate and store it in a keyvault using terraform. I found this [azurerm_app_service_certificate_order](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/app_service_certificate_order#csr) that can order the certificate, however the certificate is in hold until I manually go to the gui and add it to a keyvault. Can this step be automated with terraform ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show your configuration block for this resource. Will help with troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [azurerm_key_vault_certificate](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/key_vault_certificate) resource to add a certificate having the path `certificate-to-import.pfx` as shown in the example below:

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault_certificate" "example" {
  name         = "imported-cert"
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id

  certificate {
    contents = filebase64("certificate-to-import.pfx")
    password = ""
  }

  certificate_policy {
    issuer_parameters {
      name = "Self"
    }

    key_properties {
      exportable = true
      key_size   = 2048
      key_type   = "RSA"
      reuse_key  = false
    }

    secret_properties {
      content_type = "application/x-pkcs12"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The problem with that is I have to create the certificate before importing it. The advantage if I use app service certificate is that I can create everything I need during the deployment and destroy it as much as I want.

Comment: So, you can generate the certificate in Keyvault during the deployment and then bind it to the App service. Check the example for generating cert in the Keyvault: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/key_vault_certificate#example-usage-generating-a-new-certificate

Comment: azurerm_app_service_certificate_binding can be used to bind cert to the App service: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/app_service_certificate_binding

Comment: Yes generate a certificate with the keyvault works, but it need to create an account with a CA issuer. The point of using App Service Certificate is that I can generate and manage the certificate directly in azure. It can be done manually from the gui, I would like to automate it with terraform.

Comment: Did you find a way to do this @Tanguy_B ? I need to do a similar thing.

Comment: Unfortunately not with App Service Certificate. I'm using Azure Keyvault certificate to order the SSL from a CA authority

Comment: I can't work out how to do that in Terraform, to import the certificate over from Azure KeyVault, question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71695811/terraform-bind-ssl-certificate-to-azure-webapp do you have the code to do that? Please would really appreciate it.