# How to import a an azure web app certificate using terraform from an azure key vault

Tags: azure, terraform-provider-azure

I have a certificate for an app service in an azure keyvault, I want to import a key vault certificate to my web app in terraform but am not sure where i would refer to the keyvault in the below example?

```
  resource "azurerm_app_service_certificate_binding" "example" {
  hostname_binding_id = azurerm_app_service_custom_hostname_binding.example.id
  certificate_id      = azurerm_app_service_managed_certificate.example.id
  ssl_state           = "SniEnabled"
}
```

Comment: Hello @itye1970, did the suggested solution work for you? Please do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot or else do accept it for helping other community members

Answer (score 2):

*To bind the existing key vault certificate with your webapp need to use as mentioned* *below by @json* *we need to first call key vault certificate using data then bind with webapp* .

> ```
> //First Read the External Key Vault
> data "azurerm_key_vault" "production_keyvault" {
>   name                = "testingkeyvault2022"
>   resource_group_name = "KeyVaultWestEuropeBackend"
> }
>
> // Now Read the Certificate
> data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "prod_certificate" {
>   name         = "testcert"
>   key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.production_keyvault.id
> }
>
> // Now bind the webapp to the domain and look for certificate. 
> resource "azurerm_app_service_custom_hostname_binding" "website_app_hostname_bind" { //Website App
>   depends_on = [
>     azurerm_app_service_certificate.cert,
>   ]
>   hostname            = var.websiteurlbind
>   app_service_name    = data.azurerm_app_service.read_website_app.name
>   resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.Terraform.name
>   ssl_state           = "SniEnabled"
>   thumbprint          = azurerm_app_service_certificate.cert.thumbprint
> }
>
>
> // Get Certificate from External KeyVault
> resource "azurerm_app_service_certificate" "cert" {
>   name                = "testingcert"
>   resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.Terraform.name
>   location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.Terraform.location
>   pfx_blob            = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.prod_certificate.value
> }
> ```

Note:- *I have not tested due to some access issue from my end*,but it should work.

*Please find this* [***SO THREAD***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71695811/terraform-bind-ssl-certificate-to-azure-webapp) *for more information.*

If still the issue persists please re-open at this [***GitHub***](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/8746) issue.

Comment: ok so the certs are not stored in secrets but in certificates , the above code specifies secrets. How can we use the certificates option?